# No Output from grep or fgrep with -f option not working

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

I have the following regular expression in a file. BTW, im on SunOS

Ex: File pattern contains the following lines:

```
Ora-[0-9]
violated
```

I have a file "**datafile**" which contain the following:

```
0:/scm/123451/test1.sql:dbuser@database:databasedb:no:yes:ORA-1234|key violated
1:/scm/123451/test1.sql:dbuser@database:databasedb:no:yes:ORA-|key violated
2:/scm/123451/test1_A.sql:dbuser@database:databasedb:no:yes:ORA-|key violated
3:/scm/123451/test1_B.sql:dbuser@database:databasedb:yes:yes:Violated
4.giga:key violated unique:giga
5.fifa:ora-error null value found:giga
```

Now, I want to use a command either **grep -f** or **fgrep -f** to find out the lines which match pattern file's regular expression. The below two command didn't work when patter file contained ONLY "Ora-[0-9]" line.

```
grep -if ./pattern ./datafile
frep -if ./pattern ./datafile
```

Am i missing something, does the pattern in the pattern file needs to be fixed strings?

Answer (score 2):

Try `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep`  NOT `/usr/bin/grep` which is what you seem to get the results for.  There are a lot of UNIX commands in Solaris `/usr/bin` that are old for retro-compatibility. `/usr/bin/awk` is notorious.

You can see the grep you get by default use of the `grep` command:

```
which grep
```

You can change this for your process by placing `/usr/xpg4/bin` in your PATH variable before you come to /usr/bin.  Or use `grep` as an alias for /usr/xpg4/bin/grep.

add an alias in .profile (maybe .bashrc, whatever):

```
alias grep=/usr/xpg4/bin/grep
```

change your PATH (again in .profile or wherever):

Example old PATH --

```
 PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

Example changed PATH

```
PATH=/usr/bin/xpg4/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

Changing your PATH can affect how your existing personal scripts behave, usually in minor but sometimes annoying ways.

Also consider just using `egrep -i '(ora|violated)'`  -- suggestion based on your example.  This does not require a file of patterns.  It can be as many alternations as you need.

Comment: It seems like SunOS by default grep / fgrep caused the big trouble. When I used the /usr/bin/xpg4/bin/grep or fgrep, it worked. I'm inside a script , inside a while read line LOOP and loop's input is a file. LOOP also has some variable setting which deals with ssh i.e. var1="$(ssh -nq ... ... "....")"; In this case, xpg4 grep/fgrep is NOT working?

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't notice that the pattern matches only "Ora" but if you look in your datafile you have a "ora" and a "ORA" but not "Ora". Hence, either include case-insensitive matching or correct the pattern.

EDIT:
Apologies, bit late here. I didn't notice the SunOS. Seems that on SunOS the grep implementation differs since it runs normally on my linux box here. Issue of Solaris grep?

Comment: that's why im using -i option with fgrep or grep